# Take out elements of a list up to a certain value

Tags: c#, list

How can I take out all elements of a list up to a certain value, and then get a list that has the rest of the values.

Ex.  List would be : 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0

I want new List: 1,1,1,1,0,0

I believe it is using List.Skip method, but not sure.

This is my list right now, containing 0's and 1's like my example(just much bigger.)

Would it be something like :

```
List<string> Values;
newList=Values.Skip(X=x=>"1")
```

Comment: What's the logic here? Skip all the zeros and take whatever after that?

Comment: Do you have to use `LINQ`? a simple `while` loop would suffice: `while(values.Length > 0 && values[0] != "1"){values.RemoveAt(0);}`

Comment: `Values.Skip(6);`?

Comment: To skip all elements until `"1"` is reached you can use `Values.SkipWhile(x != "1")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SkipWhile` method to skip until you hit the value you want to start taking.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>() { "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0" };
List<string> newList = values.SkipWhile(x => !x.Equals("1")).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", newList));

// Prints
1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the items starting from the first item that is `1`, you can use `List.IndexOf()` to get the index of the first `1` that appears on your list, then use `Skip()` to get the rest of the items.

```
var list = new List<int>() { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 };
var fromFirst1Value = list.Skip(list.IndexOf(1));
```

If you break it down, `list.IndexOf(1)` will return the index of the first `1` in your list, which in the above example is `6`. Then the `Skip()` will get you all the elements starting from that index.

If on the other hand you simply want to get all the elements at a certain index you can simply pass that index to the `Skip()` method:

```
var fromSomeIndex = list.Skip(5);
```

This will return all elements in the list starting at index `5` (which is the 6th element).

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<string> Values;
    var newList = new List<string>;
    bool start = false;
    
    foreach (string value in Values)
    {
    if (value == "0" && start == false)
    {
    continue;
    }
    else
    {
start = true;
    newList.Add(value);
    }
    }
```

Might work?